# Apache does not start after instal

Tags: apache

So i have installed apache and got this error so now it does not start how do I fix this ?

[image: error]

Comment: Are you running something else that binds to port 80, like IIS or Skype?

Answer (score 0):

I found this :

Open up your httpd.conf file in apache2/conf, look for the line that starts with Listen usually around line number 120 or so.See that it is set up to Listen on 80 or whatever port you wanted, look for ServerName line and put either localhost or 127.0.0.1, save the file and check again

and it solved my problem, i got "It works!"